# ImportError with PyInstaller (using module pattern.de)

Tags: design-patterns, importerror, pyinstaller

I’m using a module named pattern.de (http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-de) to implement a tool for text mining. To make it available for my colleagues I wanted to convert it into a standalone application. That for I’m using PyInstaller. When I run the final executable file I get the following ImportError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pattern.de
test returned -1
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

To make it easier to find a solution I reduced my script to the crucial part:

```
from pattern.de import parse, split
```

This is what I entered to start PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --name=test --hiddenimport pattern.de --debug "C:\Users\BBlag\PycharmProjects\LDA\test.py"
```

As you can see I added pattern.de explicitly as hiddenimport. But while PyInstaller runs it shows me that it is not able to find the module:

```
108 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pattern.de'
1215 ERROR: Hidden import 'pattern.de' not found
```

I’m pretty new to programming so please excuse if this question is trivial. I have been wondering if it could be connected to the fact, that the module itself (when it is being downloaded and installed) is called simply ‘pattern’. ‘Pattern.de’ is used to import the german version of the package. That’s why I also tried to hiddenimport ‘pattern’. When I do so, I don’t receive the above mentioned error from PyInstaller (here it finds the right module), but when executing the final application I get the following similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named de
test returned -1
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

The application obviously is missing the ‘de part’ here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(For posterity)

I had a similar problem with 'pattern.en'. My problem was fixed when I told pyinstaller to import 'pattern.text'. 'en', 'de', etc are actually contained in that directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues with pattern.en and en-model.slp. I came up with a temporary fix which works for me smoothly. There might be a better way to solve it though:

1. Instead of importing "pattern.en", import "pattern.text.en" as this is actually how it appears
2. The executable was unable to find "en-model.slp" file. In the '<dir_path>/pattern/text/en/init.py', en-model.slp is defined as model = os.path.join(MODULE, "en-model.slp")
3. At the top of the **init**.py where MODULE variable is defined, I temporality changed variable to empty string so that the executable finds the .slp file in the current directory (like this, MODULE = "").
4. After the executable is created, I copied the "en-model.slp" file to the same dist directory where my executable is created. This way my executable started working.
5. Reverted back all the changes in **init**.py